# Horse racing: Determining true odds from posted odds

Tags: probability

I'm trying to figure out the true odds of a given horse winning a race against other horses.  Before a race, odds are posted on a big board: horse A is 2:1, horse B is 5:1, etc.  Let's assume these odds are accurate--that is, the betting is spot-on.

The problem is that when you sum these odds they come out to more than 100%  Here's a recent race:

Horse A: 6/1 = 14%
Horse B: 9/5 = 36%
Horse C: 5/2 = 29%
Horse D: 4/1 = 20%
Horse E: 9/2 = 18%
Horse F: 8/1 = 11%
Total = 128%

This is due, I think, to the fact that the racetrack takes a cut of the winnings in these "paramutuel" betting systems.  Not really concerned with the specifics.

Instead, what I would like to know is, upon picking up the Racing Form in the morning and seeing the data, like the above, how (if, indeed it is possible) I can calculate the true odds (on the assumption that the data given is correct) from the data.  It would have to sum to 100%.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If we assume that the odds have been overestimated **evenly** to account for the racetrack profit cut, the real odds will be proportional (e.g. for Horse A with 14% of a total 128%, real odds would be 10.9375%).

Comment: I'm curious how true this assumption is in practice.

Comment: @Travis good point.  I bet in such a big business they have trends on whether wagerers are more likely to overestimate a favorite or underdog's chances relative to reality. Would be interesting to see.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to @Javi, to calculate each proportion, just divide the posted Percentage by 1.28.
$$\frac{.14}{1.28}\approx10.94\% \text{ for Horse A}\\\frac{.36}{1.28}\approx28.13\% \text{ for Horse B}$$